# Gson for mixed values (boolean, int, String) from a Map

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I'm creating `JsonObject` from `Map<String, String>` with `Gson`:

```
val params = HashMap<String, String>()
params["confirmation"] = "send"    
JsonParser().parse(Gson().toJson(params)) as JsonObject
```

It works fine when all entries are Strings (hence the `Map<String, String>`). However, I find myself unable to use this method to create a mixed-value Json, such as it the following example:

```
{
  "integer": 1,
  "string": "text",
  "boolean": false
}
```

Is there a way of accomplishing such results without creating models and POJOs? I found some workarounds, but I'm looking forward to see an elegant solution, maybe a Map with generic (or even wildcard) types..

Comment: ... Like, a JsonObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically I found an answer by trial-and-error method. It was all about extending the parametrized type to `Any` (`Object` in Java). Here is how it works:

```
val params = HashMap<String, Any>()
params["integer"] = 123   
params["string"] = "text"   
params["boolean"] = false    
JsonParser().parse(Gson().toJson(params)) as JsonObject
```

This code results in a mixed typed JsonObject, as follows:

```
{
  "integer": 123,
  "string": "text",
  "boolean": false
}
```